# Secure Page Tab URL will be required on October 1, 2011

Tags: facebook, ssl

Does anyone know what's going to happen to your apps if you don't provide a secure url, I've got a whole bunch of apps which pull facebook styled pages from there site to use on there facebook page.

Comment: Since [the relevant post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/497) explicitly says "required", I'd guess that non-HTTPS apps will not be allowed / will be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I imagine it will be similar to the case where you provide only an insecure URL and the user has HTTPS enabled (When they attempt to go to your app it will result in an error message being displayed to the user).
Currently the user can elect to switch off HTTPS temporarily, but I wouldn't expect that to be the case once HTTPS is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Well - they will probably appear broken. You are better off migrating all of them to a secure ssl hosting server as soon as you can.